# java program can't find symbol class Node but I imported it

Tags: java, import, package, nodes

My program keeps stating that it cannot find the symbol Node but I have imported the package.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Client
{
public static void main(String []args){
    Node aNode = new Node(210);
    Node bNode = new Node(921);
    Node cNode = new Node(432);
    Node dNode = new Node(123);
    Node eNode = new Node(654);
   }

}
```

I know that that as of right now this code does not do anything but it is just a snippet of the code where the problem is occuring.

Comment: "_but I imported it_" Where? What kind of `Node` are you trying to use?

Comment: So what would I have to do to fix this issue? Im sorry if im misunderstanding some things im still relatively new to computer programming i appreciate the help however

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve. You don't mention that in your question. What kind of `Node` are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use the Node from LinkedList, I am making a radix sort for a computer science class. Initially, we were instructed to create our own linkedlist and node class and I was able to complete the program with my own versions. However, he would now like us to use the Java linkedlist class that is built in.

Comment: The `Node` class from `java.util.LinkedList` would need to be accessed as `java.util.LinkedList.Node` (or just `LinkedList.Node` if you import `java.util.*`). However this is a strictly internal class to the `java.util.LinkedList` (it is declared as `private static class`), so you cannot access it from outside (and you don't need to access it to use `java.util.LinkedList`)

Comment: As Thomas said It's private. [But it's a small class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l970). You can easily copy it to a class that you can access. That class does require three parameters, non of which are integers, so I'm not too sure what those numbers mean?

Comment: Our teacher will not allow us to copy the class. That was my initial thought at first also and the node class we created before took only an integer parameter i have to change this based on the real node class java has provided. I will try to institute these changes and will let you know how it goes thank you both for your help